# Resolve a dependency as the parent in .Net core

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, dbcontext

Is it possible to resolve parent object, when only a child class is registered in the container.

Here is my case. I register `MyDbContext` which is derived from `DbContext`.

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
```

Is it possible to resolve above instance as `DbContext`

```
 DbContext applicationContext = context.RequestServices.GetService<DbContext>();
```

Currently I get null for above code. Is it possible to resolve this from container some how. I need to do this because above code is in the middle ware which is framework/infrastructure code.

Comment: Only if you register it with the DI container. ie `services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDbContext>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to register the `DbContext` with the DI container so that it can be mapped when resolved.

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDbContext>();
```

That way any time `DbContext` is requested it will resolve to `MyDbContext`